# Making non normal data normal

Tags: r, spss, normal-distribution

I have a data set containing two variables(Attitude and Re Purchase_Intention) and i want to check their normality separately.
I took log, Ln and square root in SPSS as well as in R but it's still non normal data and also performed the normality tests but it's not benefiting me because i want to know how that data can be made normal.
so i'm finding it difficult to proceed for further analysis.
kindly help

Comment: How can anyone help without seeing the data? Use 'dput(yourdata)' and post output here. In addition, this post may help you: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77882/how-can-i-make-my-data-fit-normal-distribution

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: a) This is not a programming question and thus off-topic on Stackoverflow. b) If your data is not normal, it's not normal. Either use a test that is robust to breaches of normality or more preferably use non-parametric or other methods that don't require normality.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that would answer your question. 
To force a vector to have distribution as close to standard normal as possible while preserving relative rankings you can apply this function to it:

```
quantNorm = function(x){qnorm(rank(x,ties.method = "average")/(length(x)+1))}
```

A sample code:

```
hist(quantNorm(1:10000),100)
```

Comment: @ AndreyShabalin: Is there any name for this method of normalization?

Comment: Normal quantile normalization or normal quantile transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the normalisation as `log(c + x)` where `x` is your variable and `c` is some constant value. You can try to find the optimal `c` value using a grid search.

Answer (score 0):

The Box-Cox transformation does this. There's a function in the MASS package (and other packages) to do it:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-58.1/topics/boxcox
https://r-coder.com/box-cox-transformation-r/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).